# How do I pull out a certain segment from a string

Tags: python, json, yahoo-finance

I'm using an API that is giving me and output formatted as

```
 ['{"quote":{"symbol":"AAPL"', '"companyName":"Apple Inc."', '"primaryExchange":"Nasdaq Global Select"', '"sector":"Technology"', '"calculationPrice":"close"', '"open":367.88', '"openTime":1593696600532', '"close":364.11', '"closeTime":1593720000277', '"high":370.47', '"low":363.64', '"latestPrice":364.11'}]
```

...(it keeps going like this with many more categories.)

I am attempting to pull out only the latest price. What would be the best way to do that?

This is what I have but I get a bunch of errors.

```
string = (data.decode("utf-8"))
    data_v = string.split(',')

    for word in data_v[latestPrice]:
        if word == ["latestPrice"]:
            print(word)


    print(data_v)
```

Comment: This is a basic [JSON structure that you should parse](https://realpython.com/python-json/) and extract elements from the dictionary.

Comment: if possible better to add your data in dictionary format then string format

Comment: What errors are you encontering?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/coby/PycharmProjects/radius final/main.py", line 29, in <module>
    current_value_AAPL()
  File "C:/Users/coby/PycharmProjects/radius final/main.py", line 22, in current_value_AAPL
    for word in data_v[latestPrice]:
NameError: name 'latestPrice' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the output this is JSON. To parse this easily use the JSON module (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html ).

If I'm correct you got this output from Yahoo Finance, if this indeed the case don't fetch and parse it manually but use the yfinance module (see https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/ )

Comment: I am actually using the iex finance api listed on rapid api but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `JSON` module to parse this `JSON` string. You can convert it into dictionary then. I have indented the JSON code for ease of understanding. You can use the following approach,

```
import json

text_to_parse = """
  {"quote":
     {
         "symbol":"AAPL",
          "companyName":"Apple Inc.",
          "primaryExchange":"Nasdaq Global Select",
          "sector":"Technology",
          "calculationPrice":"close",
          "open":367.88,
          "openTime":1593696600532,
          "close":364.11,
          "closeTime":1593720000277,
          "high":370.47,
          "low":363.64,
          "latestPrice":364.11
     }
 }
"""

parsed_dict = json.loads(text_to_parse)
print(parsed_dict["quote"]["latestPrice"])
```

When the program is run, it outputs `364.11`

Comment: that number is not always 364.11, it is constantly changing. Every time I make a request to the api that number will change. I need a way to extract it every time.

Comment: It will not be always 364.11. The code will still work. You will have to pass the JSON string to json.loads() function :)